# Why does this for loop not work in parallel?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to run a function in parallel in a linux version of R. However, I keep finding that each parallel iteration returns `NULL` rather than the output of the function. I have isolated the problem to a for loop.

Here is a simplified version:

```
library(parallel)

rows <- seq(1,9,1)

for_test <- function(i){
  for (s in 1:3){
    print(i*s) 
  }
}

cls <- makeCluster(length(rows), type = 'FORK')

parLapply(cls, rows, for_test)

stopCluster(cls)
```

This returns `NULL` for each of the nine iterations, but changing the `for_test` function to:

```
for_test <- function(i){
  s <- 2
  print(i*s)
}
```

returns the result of `i*s` rather than `NULL`. I have run for loops within parallel previously and can't seem to figure out why it isn't working on this occasion. Is anyone able to point to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: the loop **works** in parallel, we just don't see the `print`. The returned `NULL` is not a result of the `print` function, it is the list of function return values from parallel calls. Instead of `print`, collect the values and return it. Printing to an external file will also work, but I suggest to start with the ordinary way first, as `parLapply` collates the return values in a convenient way.

As an example how to use return values, try the following:

```
library(parallel)

rows <- seq(1,9,1)

for_test <- function(i){
  txt <- NULL
  for (s in 1:3){
    txt <- rbind(txt, c(i, s, i*s))
  }
  txt
}

cls <- makeCluster(length(rows))
parLapply(cls, rows, for_test)
stopCluster(cls)
```

**Explanation:**

In the first example of the OP `print`is within a `for loop`, while in the second version it is the last statement. `print` returns a value while `for()`returns `NULL`.

**Demo:**

```
> x <- print(2)
[1] 2
> x
[1] 2
> 
> x <- for (i in 1:2) print(2 * i)
[1] 2
[1] 4
> x
NULL
>
```

Comment: Thank you for this thorough example, I think I am starting to see why the actual code I am trying to run in parallel doesn't work. So does this mean that when running in parallel I can't run a function within a for loop, and save those outputs to disk? I would need to collate the outputs from each iteration of the loop and save them outside of it?

Comment: The problem is the `print`not the `for` loop. (1) You can save outputs to disc, but (afaik) not print to the console. (2) the functions just need to return the results and `parLapply` collates the results conveniently for you.